# how to translate all your data in R using google API

Tags: r, google-api, google-translate

I am working on twitter data and want to translate my data from Arabic to English using google translate API in R. I am using the translate() package and this is my code:

```
library(translate)
library(readxl)

my_data <- read_excel("tweets.xlsx")


gar_auth(email="fatima@ekadkom.com")

set.key('AIzaSyD-KhXNAHcKWVvAEzgtNM2rwEX_lEHmWz4')

getOption("google.key")

my_translate <- Vectorize(translate)

t <- sapply(my_data$text, my_translate , source="ar", target="en", get.key())
```

However once I run it I only get the first line/ record of my data translated, How can I run the translation on my entire data?

Comment: add package name and some example data

Comment: It looks to me like you're using the unvectorised version of  `translate`.  What happens with `t <- sapply(my_data$text, my_translate, source="ar", target="en")`.  As @Roman says, some sample data would help us to help you.

Comment: @Roman Edited my code with example data